# How to report buyer penalty on sale of house to the IRS?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1040, house-sale

I sold my house last year. A portion of the house included a residential rental. The buyer was several weeks late closing escrow. I charged the buyer a per day penalty to cover my mortgage interest and property taxes, which amounted to a couple thousand dollars. However, now I am wondering how to report that cash to the IRS (and I am annoyed that I didn’t charge him enough to cover my taxes).

Note: the title company did send me Form 1099-S. Line 2 (Gross proceeds) did *not* include the buyer penalty, and Box 4 (other consideration) was *not* checked.

Questions:

1. In [Pub 523, Selling Your Home](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-publication-523) Worksheet 2, should the buyer penalty be included in Line 1 “All money (currency, check, wire transfer)” in the **sale price** of the house? Note: for me I am was well below the $250k limit on eligible exclusion of gain.
2. In [Form 4797, Sales of Business Property](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-4797) Line 2 property table, should the buyer penalty be included in column (d) **Gross sale price**, despite the fact that it was not reported in Form 1099-S?
3. Should the buyer penalty be included anywhere else e.g. [Form 1040](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1040) Schedule 1 Line 8 **Other Income**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Treat it as an addition to the sale price. You sold the house for $X, and charged the buyer additional $Y due to being late - your total gross sale price was $(X+Y).